# PHP DAO classes inherit from a generic DAO classes and only change the table name

Tags: php, object-oriented, pdo

I am building a web app that needs to access various tables in a given MySQL db.  To do that, I have created a generic class, see `DAO_DBRecord.php` below, and I create children classes for each table I want to access, e.g., `DAO_User.php` is used to access the `users` table.  The only difference in the children classes is that I change the value of the variable which contains the name of the table I wish to access.

My questions are:
1 - Should I make the `DAO_DBRecord.php` class abstract?  I'm not planning to instantiate it, and in fact as it is written I cannot access any table with it.
2 - Should I use constants in the `DAO_DBRecord.php` class (e.g., `const USER_TABLENAME = 'users';  const ARTICLE_TABLENAME = 'articles';`) and reference them in the children classes (e.g., `private Stable = USER_TABLENAME;`)?
3 - Anything else I should do?

**Class_DB.php:**

```
<?php
    class DB {
        private $dbHost;
        private $dbName;
        private $dbUser;
        private $dbPassword;

        function __construct($dbHost, $dbName, $dbUser, $dbPassword) {
            $this->dbHost=$dbHost;
            $this->dbName=$dbName;
            $this->dbUser=$dbUser;
            $this->dbPassword=$dbPassword;
        }

        function createConnexion() {
            return new PDO("mysql:host=$this->dbHost;dbname=$this->dbName", 
                        $this->dbUser, $this->dbPassword);
        }
    }
?>
```

**DAO_DBRecord.php**

```
<?php
    require_once('Class_DB.php');

    class DAO_DBrecord {
        private $dbh; // This is an instance of Class_DB to be injected in the functions.
        private $table=NULL;

        function __construct($dbh){
            $this->dbh=$dbh;
        }
        function dbConnect(){
            $dbConnection=$this->dbh->createConnexion();
            return $dbConnection;
        }
        function checkRecordExists($recordIdentifier, $tableColName){
            $dbConnection=$this->dbConnect();
            $query=$dbConnection->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table "
                . "WHERE $tableColName = :recordIdentifier");
            $query->bindParam(":recordIdentifier", $recordIdentifier);
            $query->execute();
            $result=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if ($result["COUNT(*)"]>0){
                return true;
            } else return false;
        }
    }
?>
```

**DAO_Users.php**

```
<?php
    class DAO_User extends DAO_DBRecord {
        private $table='users';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why not something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/368990/567663 ?

Comment: Sorry Paul - I don't understand your link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>If the only difference between subclasses of `DAO_DBRecord` is the table name I wouldn't use subclasses. I'd just pass the table name to to the constructor of `DAO_DBRecord` and use different instances for different tables.</del>

If the only difference between subclasses of `DAO_DBRecord` is the table name I would pass the name of the table to the constructor of the parent class:

```
class UserDao extends DAO_DBRecord {

    public function __construct($db) {
        parent::__construct($db, 'users');
    }
}
```

Having different classes improves type safety. In Java you can't pass a `UserDao` to a method with an `ArticleDao` parameter(1), it does not compile. I don't know whether this kind of type safety exists in PHP or not, but it could be a good practice and could results more readable code.

(1) Of course except if `UserDao` is a subclass of `ArticleDao`

---

I don't feel that making `DAO_DBRecord` class abstract would make a big difference. If your clients wants to misuse the class they can create a dummy (non-abstract) subclass for that:

```
class AnyDao extends DAO_DBRecord {

    public function __construct($db, $tableName) {
        parent::__construct($db, $tableName);
    }
}
```

If you want to protect `DAO_DBRecord` from instantiation with unknown table names make its constructor `private` and create static factory functions for your tables inside the `DAO_DBRecord`:

```
class DAO_DBrecord {
        private $db;
        private $tableName;

        private function __construct($db, $tableName) {
            $this->db = $db;
            $this->tableName = $tableName;
        }

        public static function createUserDao($db) {
            return new DAO_DBrecord($db, 'users');
        }

        public static function createArticleDao($db) {
            return new DAO_DBrecord($db, 'articles');
        }
        ...
}
```

So, `DAO_DBrecord` cannot be used with other tables.

---

If you use your table names only once creating constants for them looks unnecessary in this case.

Comment: That's the way I had it before, then I thought it would be better programming to separate it, just in case I end up having different needs for different tables.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I've forgotten type safety for a moment. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you think the parent class should be abstract?

Comment: Check the update, please.

Comment: Why do you make the static functions `createUserDao` and `createArticleDao` private?

Comment: That's the default :), it was a typo, I've fixed it. Thanks for pointing this out.